# How to have foreman 1.4 to dispay long puppet class names

Tags: foreman

I have long puppet class names in my module. Like: my_cluster_module::role::java::services::some_service_name.

When trying to add such role to a virtual machine via the "Puppet Classes" tab, only the first ~ 30 characters are shown in the Available Classes section. The search bar also seems to lookup only those shorten strings.

How do i extend the display length?

Answer (score 0):

1) Modify lenght (28 to 128 for example):

```
/usr/share/foreman/app/helpers/application_helper.rb

klass.name, :length => 128
```

2) Adjust CSS adding:

```
/var/lib/foreman/public/assets/application.css
/var/lib/foreman/public/assets/application-5ab8acb867832352a54dadd52918fa0a.css

#puppet_klasses .col-md-6 {
  width: 60% !important;
}
```

3) Restart Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```